# character stops after second key pressed is lifted

Tags: javascript, canvas, keyboard

I'm taking input from the arrow keys and moving a character accordingly on a 2D canvas game in JavaScript.

When I press two keys, I want special things to happen like moving diagonally and stopping.

These special things do happen, however there is a glitch when I lift up the second key that was pressed down: my character stops moving.  This doesn't happen, though, if I lift the first key pressed and keep the second key pressed.  In that case, my character continues in that direction.  Why does this occur??

**Here is a snippet of the function:**

```
//both up and down keys pressed, character should stop
if(Keys.up && Keys.down){
    character.y -= 10;
    character.y += 10;
}
else if(Keys.down){
    character.y += 10;
}
else if(Keys.up){
    character.y -= 10;
}
```

Also, I am taking the input from `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events and storing them in an object called Keys.  (e.g. `Keys[e.keyCode] = true )`
When the key is pressed, that key's boolean value is true.  When lifted it is false.

Comment: Going to need to see more code than just that snippet.  Particularly, the onKeyUp method.

Comment: Seems like too complex control. Why not just use separate keys for that special things?

Answer (score 0):

To move diagonal, you need an x component, not just a Y. So you need a listener for both x and y.

Also, for this, why not just do (instead of forcing the client to do the calculations for no reason):

```
if(Keys.up && Keys.down){
    return;
}
```

Also, when you add the X component, dont use "else if" - just use "if" as you want to be able to capture more than one input at a time to move diagonally.

Should look something like:

```
if(Keys.up && Keys.down){
    return;
}
if(Keys.down){
    character.y += 10;
}
if(Keys.up){
    character.y -= 10;
}
if(Keys.left){
    character.x -= 10;
}
if(Keys.right){
    character.x += 10;
}
```

You can also do interpolation using CSS animation to move between the positions in order to make the movement smoother (and not jump 10px each button press).