# Why does my ball stop after I've released one of two pressed arrow key?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, 2d

I try to make a game with HTML5/Javascript, where two players drive a balls to get in one bigger ball.

My program listen `keydown` and `keyup` events, then write statuses of the buttons to `keyMaps` array, and use this array to decide where should move the balls.

---

There is a trouble with driving the players balls.
I press simultaneously two arrow buttons (for example "left" and "up") on the keyboard to drive diagonal direction. After this when I release last pressed (to PC mind), my ball stop. But when I release first pressed (to PC mind) button my ball doesn't stop.

Also, I've looked at console log in my browser and find that when I press two buttons (for example "left arrow" and "up arrow") only one of the two events continue to pass in `movePlayer()` function. Same question was here: [character stops after second key pressed is lifted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137132/character-stops-after-second-key-pressed-is-lifted), but not solved.

---

Why only one of the two events continue to pass in `movePlayer()` function and how I can get round of this?

Here is a code of my program:

```
    function movePlayer(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    keyMaps[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

        if ((keyMaps[37]==true) && (keyMaps[40]==true)) {
            xP1 -= velocity; yP1 += velocity;
        }
        
        if ((keyMaps[37]==true) && (keyMaps[38]==true)) {
            xP1 -= velocity; yP1 -= velocity;
        }
        
        if ((keyMaps[39]==true) && (keyMaps[40]==true)) {
            xP1 += velocity; yP1 += velocity;
        }
        
        if ((keyMaps[39]==true) && (keyMaps[38]==true)) {
            xP1 += velocity; yP1 -= velocity;
        }
        
        if ((keyMaps[65]==true) && (keyMaps[83]==true)) {
            xP2 -= velocity; yP2 += velocity;
        }
        
        if ((keyMaps[65]==true) && (keyMaps[87]==true)) {
            xP2 -= velocity; yP2 -= velocity;
        }
        
        if ((keyMaps[68]==true) && (keyMaps[83]==true)) {
            xP2 += velocity; yP2 += velocity;
        }
        
        if ((keyMaps[68]==true) && (keyMaps[87]==true)) {
            xP2 += velocity; yP2 -= velocity;
        }
        
        if (keyMaps[37] && !keyMaps[40] && !keyMaps[38] && !keyMaps[39]) {
            xP1 -= velocity;
        }
        
        if (!keyMaps[37] && keyMaps[40] && !keyMaps[38] && !keyMaps[39]) {
            yP1 += velocity;
        }
        
        if (!keyMaps[37] && !keyMaps[40] && keyMaps[38] && !keyMaps[39]) {
            yP1 -= velocity;
        }
        
        if (!keyMaps[37] && !keyMaps[40] && !keyMaps[38] && keyMaps[39]) {
            xP1 += velocity;
        }
        
        if (keyMaps[65] && !keyMaps[83] && !keyMaps[87] && !keyMaps[68]) {
            xP2 -= velocity;
        }
        
        if (!keyMaps[65] && keyMaps[83] && !keyMaps[87] && !keyMaps[68]) {
            yP2 += velocity;
        }
        
        if (!keyMaps[65] && !keyMaps[83] && keyMaps[87] && !keyMaps[68]) {
            yP2 -= velocity;
        }
        
        if (!keyMaps[65] && !keyMaps[83] && !keyMaps[87] && keyMaps[68]) {
            xP2 += velocity;
        }
    }   
    document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = movePlayer;
```

Comment: Changing `console.log(event.keyCode);` to `console.log(e.keyCode);` got movePlayer working to some extent. Please cut the code down to a minimal test case that demonstrates the problem if one still remains - it doesn't need to be a playable gme.

Comment: Thank you, @Traktor53. I've edited my code: there are only function and event listener now. I also have changed "event" to "e". But nothing changed in balls behavior.